# How do I edit the "Application" meta-property of a PDF file?

Tags: pdf

I need to change the Application meta-property of an existing, non-protected PDF File. None of the online or off-line editors seems to do the trick.

With the tools below, I can change creation date, author, etc but no the field that says on which application the PDF was created.

I've tried:

- Libre Office Draw
- Adobe DC
- PDFEdit
- WonderShare

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish. That is, why do you believe you need to modify this property?

Comment: I want the document to appear it came, for example, from Microsoft Word, even if it was changed by another software.